# select a data from list and store in a variable in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

hi I new to phonegap android in I had created a list using jquery which contains data from local database. know what i want to do is select a data from list and to store that selected list in variable. the code for creating list is here

```
function getdata(){
 db.transaction(function(tx)
         {
            tx.executeSql(selectdata,[],function(tx,results){
                $('#name').empty();
                    for(var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++){
                    $('#name').append('<li id="s1" onclick="selectname()"><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+results.rows.item(i).nameR+'</h3></a></li>');
                    //parent.location='file:///android_asset/www/editpage.html';
                    }   
            }); 
         });
```

}

```
function selectname(){
var strnme=document.getElementsByClassName("ui-hi-heading").value;
alert("Data Selected is"+strnme);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can store the list data in Object variable :-

```
var data_obj = {};   

function getdata(){
   db.transaction(function(tx)  
     {  
        tx.executeSql(selectdata,[],function(tx,results){  
            $('#name').empty();  
                for(var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++){ 


                  //$('#name').append('<li id="s1" onclick="selectname()"><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+results.rows.item(i).nameR+'</h3></a></li>');


                  //change here
                  $('#name').append('<li id="s"'+ i +' onclick="selectname('+i+','+results.rows.item(i).nameR+')"><a href="#"><h3   class="ui-li-heading">'+results.rows.item(i).nameR+'</h3></a></li>');  




                //parent.location='file:///android_asset/www/editpage.html';  
                }       
        });   
     });  
}
```

change your selectname() function:-

```
function selectname(i, my_data){
  data_obj[i] = my_data;
  var strnme=document.getElementsByClassName("ui-hi-heading").value;
  alert("Data Selected is"+strnme);
}
```

and your data_obj will contain your list data.

Comment: what i want is to store the data which user will select.

Comment: i want to store only the selected data not complete list for eg: consider this list name1,name2,name3 when user will select name1 it will store name1 in the variable. and i tried ur solution its giving this error 06-05 11:38:06.123: D/CordovaLog(947): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Neerav
06-05 11:38:06.123: E/Web Console(947): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Neerav at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:88

Comment: i think you you miss this line of code:
$('#name').append('<li id="s1" onclick="selectname('+i+','+results.rows.item(i).nameR+')"><a href="#"><h3   class="ui-li-heading">'+results.rows.item(i).nameR+'</h3></a></li>');

Comment: thanks its giving error bcz we are passing variable in onclick so i didn't use results.rows.item(i).name. and passed only the id and stored the list data in object its wrkng fine